# Convert char array of C into string of C++

Tags: c++, c, arrays, linux, string

I need to convert `char` array of C into string c++ but the `char` array is an element of `struct`.

Code:

This is my Structure in C

```
typedef struct myStruct
{
    char name[50];
    char abc[50];
    ESL_BOOL status;
}MyStruct;
```

and I want to access `name[50]` in c++ but for that I have to convert it into string.
I have tried `strcpy` and `memcpy`. 
I am using `ESL_BOOL status;` and it is working but confused with `name[50]`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first thing you should change in the `class` name in your struct because that will likely cause problems because it is a keyword in C++.

Then for converting a C string into a C++ one, you can simply use the `std::string` constructor that accepts C-style strings.

```
std::string myCppString(MyStruct.name);
```

Comment: ThanksSir I need to assign this char array to string element of

Comment: I don't understand what you want to do exactly. Do you mean like you want to copy a `char[50]` into another?

Answer (score 0):

```
typedef struct myStruct {
    char name[50];
    char mclass[50];
    ESL_BOOL status;
} MyStruct;
```

`class` is a reserved keyword of the C++ language. If you try to use it, tokenizer will take it as a keyword and cause problems later in the parsing phase, as an identifier will be expected.

It was once considered a good practice to precede all of the `struct`´s members with `m` or `m_` to avoid such collisions.

To your problem: just the default *"from C string"* `string (const char* s)` constructor should be enough.

```
MyStruct obj;
std::string objsName(obj.name);
std::string objsClass(obj.mclass);
```